# How to add Message if the data from the backend can't be received back in 50 second (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hy Guys,

I have some question about how to set message if server can't be received back in 50 second. i used angularjs factory for send request to server.

```
$http.post("https://example.com/_ah/api/tweeting/v1/xxx?average_cycle=1&date_last_stroke=2001-01-01&do_last_bp_measaure="+do_last_bp_measaure+"&googleusername="+window.localStorage.getItem('username_google')+"")
.success(function(r){
  alert(r)
}, function(error){
  alert(error)
})
```

i have try with used $timeout but same can't result message

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http check that out  , you can configure it through config .

Comment: you can use something like this: window.setTimeout(function() {
    your api call;
  }, 5000);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[$http has timeout config](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#usage):

> timeout – {number|Promise} – timeout in milliseconds, or promise that should abort the request when resolved.

Example:

```
    $http.post(
    "https://example.com/_ah/api/tweeting/v1/xxx?average_cycle=1&date_last_stroke=2001-01-01&do_last_bp_measaure="+do_last_bp_measaure+"&googleusername="+window.localStorage.getItem('username_google')+"",
    {
        'postData': 'whatever'
    },
    {
        'timeout': 50000 // 50 seconds
    }
    )
    .success(function (response) {
        console.log("Responsed in 50 seconds :)");
    })
    .error(function (response) {
        console.log("Timeout :("); // Of course it could be other errors
    });
```

Comment: pleas ask questions in comments to … question. I guess if there is timeout - user should know that reason of error was timeout or error 503 - service unavailable

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski Ok, questions go to comments next time! :D The question was how to catch timeout event I guess, so I threw rest parts to our asker.

Comment: thanks Krzysztof Safjanowski, this work for my code. sorry for my bad english :)